# Async fetch & decode of .wav file works on desktop, but not on mobile (WebAudioAPI)

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, web-audio-api, convolution

I'm currently working on a web-based synthesizer program, using WebAudioAPI. It works quite well on desktop, but on mobile it seems to fail on loading & decoding the impulse response from a wav file.

The impulse response is used in conjunction with a convolver node, to implement a convolution reverb. Oddly enough, everything else works fine on mobile - oscillators, waveshapers, gain nodes, etc, and the application itself does not stop running (as it would if there were an unhandled exception). It's almost as if the file itself is not being decoded or loaded into the convolver node properly - when I send my sources to the node, on mobile, it outputs only silence.

Here is the code I have for performing these tasks:

```
//calculate reverb impulse response & assign to convolver node buffer
calcIR();

async function calcIR() {
 let wavFile = await fetch("./wavData/ir4.wav");
 let wavBuffer = await wavFile.arrayBuffer();
 voice1.reverb.buffer = await synthCtx.decodeAudioData(wavBuffer);
}
```

in this case, **buffer** is the property of the convolver node which holds the decoded impulse response data, & **synthCtx** is my web audio context; **ir4.wav** is the actual impulse response. The async function call follows the synchronous instantiation of voice1, to make sure that the nodes are actually initialized before trying to change one of their properties.

I have not stopped playing around & troubleshooting, and I have a few more things I will probably try, but I figured I'd consult SE just to see if anyone here has an idea: ] also, just to clarify, I have indeed tested it on mobile, and I'm calling the resume() function on the context from a touchEnd event, so I know the issue isn't the context being muted. As above, everything works on mobile & sounds great - save for silence from the convolver node.

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
I've created a [small jsfiddle demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/tndk3m7g/) to illustrate the problem I'm having.

The demo uses only a single square wave, routed into two gain nodes - one to the output (destination), and one to the convolver node (which is in turn routed to the destination). A slider controls the relative mix between the two.

```
fully left is fully dry (100% directly to output, 0% to convolver)
fully right is fully wet (0% directly to output, 100% to convolver)
```

Oddly enough, it seems I'm having the same problem in the fiddle, though it works perfectly well inside of [my app](http://www.rsyn.co/db/index.html). You can hear that the oscillator fades away into silence as the slider is moved, when it should be slowly fading in the reverberated signal.

I've tried to retain similarity between implementations, ie, I am calling the **calcIR()** function at the exact same place in my demo as I am within the actual app (just after finishing the connections, and just before starting the oscillators).

I also tried throwing some **console.log()**'s within the async function, just to see how far it is progressing - seems it's not even getting past the fetch stage. I've also confirmed the wav file availability is not the issue (hosted in a gcloud storage bucket, works elsewhere without any problems).

I admit I am still fairly new to async/await & working with promises in general, so I may just be misunderstanding something here. However, I'm not sure why one way would work in one place just fine and not at all in the other, though it certainly wouldn't be the first time.

Comment: A short runnable snippet on jsfiddle, or codepen or wherever would be really helpful to see what's going on.  There just isn't enough context in your description.

Comment: sure, here's a little demo to illlustrate the basic idea: https://jsfiddle.net/tndk3m7g/.

Comment: Thanks for test case.  Don't have any thing to say except that I tried it out on desktop and mobile (Chrome Android), and I do hear the tone.  It takes a little while before the tone starts, but it's there.

Comment: Thanks. The delay you're referring to due to the audio context being suspended until the receipt of user input (in this case, slider value change, when testCtx.resume() is called). That's standard behavior of the API. Hearing the tone isn't the problem though - the tone should smoothly fade between unprocessed & reverberated when the slider is changed. Instead. the reverb node outputs only silence, which i'm guessing is a problem with the async fetch() call. Appreciate the input in any case!

Comment: Ok, I tried again on mobile.  When I move the slider full left, I hear a tone.  When I move the slider full right, there's silence.  The transition between the two is pretty smooth.